# Structute of an image output 2D-FFT array

Tags: image, image-processing, data-structures, structure, fft

I perform a 2D-FFT to a NxM image.
The converted array is sized Nx2M.
I know that in the output array there is magnitude and there is a phase, but I couldn't find the consistency

Can anyone put things in order for me? I know that the numbers I see represent frequency components, but I do not understand how there can be negative numbers in a sequence of 4 or 5 times at the first cells of the array (even if it represents the phase).
I must understand the structure of the image, before and after 2D-FFT, much better.

Im coding using CVI and there is the relevant part of the code:

```
    double  fftIn[pHeight][pWidth];
    
    for(int column=0; column<(pWidth); column++)
    {
        for(int row=0; row<pHeight; row++)
        {
            fftIn[row][column] = imageIn[row][column];
        }
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    //fourier transform
    //=================
    double      fftOut[pHeight][pWidth * 2];

    analysisErr = FFT2D(fftIn, 
                        pHeight,    //NUM_ROWS, 
                        pWidth,     //NUM_COLS, 
                        pHeight,    //NUM_ROWS,
                        pWidth,     //NUM_COLS, 
                        0, 
                        fftOut);
    
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

while trying to define double fftOut[pHeight][pWidth];
Im getting the following
[image: Error]

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should be getting a NxM complex array, not an Nx2M array. Unless you show your code, or even disclose what language and what FFT library you are using, there is no way we can guess as to the format of the data you get back.

Comment: I thought that is something common while using 2D-FFT. Im coding with CVI and I will edit the post as you suggested.

Comment: The documentation page is more than useless, it doesn't describe the format of the input or output: http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370051AG-01/cvi/libref/cvifft2d/

Comment: Did you see this post? https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabWindows-CVI/how-to-use-fft2d-labwindows/td-p/840053?profile.language=en -- It looks like the output is the complex numbers, interleaving the real and imaginary components. That is, the first two doubles are the real and imaginary components of the first output value; the next two doubles are the components of the second output value, etc.

Comment: If you get sensical results with that interpretation, please consider posting an answer below, it might be useful for future visitors (given how poor the documentation is!). You can answer and accept your own answer. These comments might be deleted, an answer is the right place for useful information.

Comment: AMAZING! thank you very much!!! If it will work for me - I will publish an answer. One more thing, if i may, just to be sure - if i want to pass the image through a filter, I need to take the root of the sum of the squares of any two adjacent cells... And the size I get represents the height of the frequency, right?

Comment: If you want to implement a filter by multiplication in the frequency domain, then you need to implement a complex multiplication. Hopefully the filter will be real-valued, in which case you just multiply the real and imaginary components of the FFT of the image by those filter values (each real+imaginary pair is multiplied by the same number). If your filter is complex-valued, you need to do 4 multiplications and two additions: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexMultiplication.html

Comment: The square root of the sum of the squares of adjacent cells would be the magnitude of the FFT, which is nice for display but not for filtering.

Comment: Ops! Missed your comment hahaha thanks a lot